# GridView.Row.Count always 0, How to solve?

Tags: asp.net

I am new in ASP.NET. I use a GridView. When I Count rows of GridView, it shows 0 always. I am giving code. But when I run the code browser, It shows data. How solve this problem?

My CS code is:

```
protected void btnSend_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string MemberList= (ViewState["Memberlist"]).ToString();
        List<PreparedEmail> preparedEmail = new List<PreparedEmail>();
        Utility util = new Utility();
        int count = 0;

        int i1 = dlClients.Rows.Count; // it shows always 0
        #region Send Invitation
        foreach (GridViewRow mail in dlClients.Rows)
        {
          //some code here, It is never execute as dlClients.Rows shows 0
         }                            
}
```

My aspx code is :

```
<asp:GridView ID="dlClients" EnableViewState="false" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ClientIDMode="Static" GridLines="None" AllowPaging="false" CssClass="table table-bordered table-striped" OnPreRender="dlClients_PreRender" DataKeyNames="MemberId" PageSize="10" ShowHeader="true">
```

And My data binding code:

```
Protected void dlClients_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<CircleUser> memberList = new CircleUserBusinessLogic().GetAll();
        dlClients.DataSource = memberList;

        dlClients.DataBind();
        //GridUpdatePanel.Update();
        ViewState["Memberlist"] = memberList;

        if (dlClients.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            //Replace the <td> with <th> and adds the scope attribute
            dlClients.UseAccessibleHeader = true;

            //Adds the <thead> and <tbody> elements required for DataTables to work
            dlClients.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;

            //Adds the <tfoot> element required for DataTables to work
            dlClients.FooterRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableFooter;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you set autogeneratedcolumns="true" in your aspx?
If you assigned autogeratecolumns true means it will be zero always.

Comment: My aspx code is :  <asp:GridView ID="dlClients" EnableViewState="false" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ClientIDMode="Static" GridLines="None" AllowPaging="false" CssClass="table table-bordered table-striped" OnPreRender="dlClients_PreRender" DataKeyNames="MemberId" PageSize="10" ShowHeader="true">  ... What should I do now?

Comment: <asp:TemplateField SortExpression="Title" HeaderText="Email"> <ItemTemplate> <div style=""> <asp:Label ID="lblMail" runat="server" CssClass="GeneralInfo" Text='<%# Bind("Email") %>'></asp:Label> </div> </ItemTemplate> </asp:TemplateField>

Comment: pls check if your viewstate is still filled by clicking on the button

Comment: @katz could not understand. I gave the code of data binding, here is also given the viewstate

Answer (score 4):

Normally asp button click event called first then gridview  prerender hits second. So the Gridview rows count is 0.

[image]

Try to bind the gridview in PageLoad Method or Button click.

here sample bind...

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(!IsPostBack )
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt = GetData();
                dlClients.DataSource = dt;

                dlClients.DataBind();
            }
        }
```

Comment: do the row count after the databind, makes sense

Answer (score 1):

The `button_click` event is called before your `prerender` event. This Means, that when the button click event is running the `databind` has not run, so the GridView is empty. To solve it, you can databind in the page's `load` event. That is called before the click events.

Answer (score 1):

Call your Gridview `PreRender` Event in Button `click` event like below:

```
        protected void btnSend_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dlClients_PreRender(sender, args);
            string MemberList = (ViewState["Memberlist"]).ToString();
            List<PreparedEmail> preparedEmail = new List<PreparedEmail>();
            Utility util = new Utility();
            int count = 0;

            int i1 = dlClients.Rows.Count;             
            foreach (GridViewRow mail in dlClients.Rows)
            {
                //some code here, It is never execute as dlClients.Rows shows 0
            }
        }
```

Comment: dlClients_PreRender(sender, args) --- I called this but didn't work

Comment: Then you can use `Page_Load` event for binding your gridview by using `IsPostBack`  property

Answer (score 1):

`EnableViewState = "true"` is a way to pass you data from one page to another